# How to display the list of folders in SWT..?

Tags: java, swt, wizard

[image]

Hi all i am developing an application in swt in which i have the condition, which is  displayed in above image..

I want to display the list  of available folders in the left box from where a user can select it in to the right box and similarly can remove it from the right box..

But is there is any way by which i can display the entire folder structure of my computers in the box..

If yes, then how can i achieve this.?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FileDialog but in your case it wont apply. So you need to use listdir() method of File class and list the files dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it would be of great help for me if you can  provide me with a little more detail.
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a root folder then you can get list of folders in the root folder using File.listdir(). Here is the api http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html here is the example http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html once you get the list of files and folders you can display them in the dialog. Here is a SWT example http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/1300__File-Tree.htm

Comment: To do what you are trying to do will require quite a bit of programming. Just to let you know that, no short cuts at least in SWT.